# display the recursion line by line

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to make a function in javascript that would expand/split a string with dashes and show the process ( line by line ) using recursion.

for example, the string "anna" would become:

```
expand("anna") = expand("an")+"---"+expand("na") ->
                 "a"+"---"+"n"+"---"+"n"+"---"+"a"
```

and the desired output would be:

```
anna
an---na
a---n---n---a
```

I have achieved doing the following so far (I know it might not be the solution I am looking):

```
expand("anna") = an+"---"+expand("na")
               = an+"---"+n+"---"+expand("a");
               = an+"---"+n+"---+"a"
```

the output I am getting is:

```
an---n---a
```

I can't seem to concatenate the head though to do the first example.

My javascript function of expand is as follows:

```
function expand(word) {
    if (word.length<=1) {
        return word;
    } else {
        mid = word.length/2;
        return word.substr(0,mid) + "  " + expand(word.substr(mid,word.length));
    }
}

document.write(expand("anna"));
```

I would need some tips to do this, otherwise (if it's the wrong stackexchange forum), please guide me where to post it.

Comment: The problem is that the recursion process the left branch of the tree first. You can not display the process steps as you wished by using recursion.

Comment: Exactly. 
I have also used the expand on the head portion of the return but it goes head function first then the tail function secondly. My problem needs to visualize (I didn't know how to express the word, that's why I put the examples) it with splitting the string as well and not only show the final result with the dashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is my crazy attempt

```
var Word = function(str) {                
    this.isSplitable = function() {
        return str.length > 1;                    
    }
    this.split = function() {
        var p = Math.floor(str.length / 2);
        return [
            new Word(str.substr(0,p)),                        
            new Word(str.substr(p,p+1))
        ];
    }        
    this.toString = function() {
        return str;
    }
}

var expand = function(words) {
    var nwords = [];
    var do_recur = false;

    words.forEach(function(word){  
        if(word.isSplitable()) {
            var splitted = word.split();
            nwords.push(splitted[0]);                                                
            nwords.push(splitted[1]);                                                
            do_recur = true;
        }else{
            nwords.push(word);
        }                 
    });

    var result = [];
    nwords.forEach(function(word){
        result.push( word.toString() );
    });

    var result = result.join("--") + "<br/>";

    if(do_recur) {
        return result + expand(nwords);
    }else{
        return "";
    }                
}

document.write( expand([new Word("anna")]) );
```

Comment: looks good except for the first `anna` that is missing. yet this is the best solution here even that i posted a solution also.

Comment: very good attempt, I think you deserve the tick :) I would like to thank you all for helping...!

Answer (score 1):

As I said that it is impossible to display the "process" steps of recursion while using recursion, here is a workaround that will output your desired steps:

```
var levels = [];

function expand(word, level) {
  if (typeof level === 'undefined') {
    level = 0;
  }
  if (!levels[level]) {
    levels[level] = [];
  }
  levels[level].push(word);
  if (word.length <= 1) {
    return word;
  } else {
    var mid = Math.ceil(word.length/2);
    return expand(word.substr(0, mid), level+1) + '---' + expand(word.substr(mid), level+1);
  }
}

expand('anna');

for (var i = 0; i < levels.length; i++) {
  console.log(levels[i].join('---'));
}
```

Comment: @EdanFeiles: You are right. I did a tiny mistake. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need

```
expand = function(word) {
    return [].map.call(word, function(x) {return x+'---'}).join('')
};
```

The joy of functional programming.

And with added code to deal with last character:

```
function expand(word) {
    return [].map.call(word, function(x, idx) {
        if (idx < word.length - 1)
            return x+'---';
        else return x
     }).join('')
}
```

Comment: I like that functional feel, it reminds me of a course I had in coursera for smlnj. That is a good one.

Comment: although it elegant solution, it produces:
a---n---n---a---
with trailing ---, and not what has been asked.

Comment: Yes I just saw it now.

Comment: I've added a second version to handle that

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the two parts of the string:

```
function expand(word) {
output="";
if (word.length<=1) {
    output+=word;
    return output;
} else 
{
    var mid = word.length/2;
    output+=word.substr(0,mid)+"---"+word.substr(mid)+" \n";//this line will show the steps.
    output+=expand(word.substr(0,mid))+"---"+expand(word.substr(mid,word.length-1))+" \n";
    return output;
}
}
console.log(expand("anna"));
```

**Edit:**

I added the `output` var and in every loop I concatenate the new output to it.

It should do the trick.

Comment: also produce: a---n---n---n---a

Comment: @EdanFeiles: The reason is that `mid` is declared as a global variable. You need to put `var` in front of it.

Comment: Yes @Amberlamps is corerct `mid` should be local to the `else` statement.

Comment: @chsdk function doesn't get to console.log()

Comment: @EdanFeiles yes you are right. I just meant to show the result of the function. Now it's done after the function.

Comment: now you are producing a string with new line in the middle:
`a---n
\n
---n---a`

Comment: Yes in fact I missed the step line, now with the new Edit It will work fine showing the result in every step.

Answer (score 0):

to see all steps the best that I whold do is:

```
function expand(word) {
    if (word.length<=1) {
        return word;
    } else {
        var mid = word.length/2;
        var str1 = word.substr(0,mid);
        var str2 = word.substr(mid,word.length);
        document.write(str1 + "---" + str2 + "<br></br>");
        return expand(str1) + "---" + expand(str2);
    }
}

document.write(expand("anna"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope the problem is in your first part. According to your algorithm, you are splitting your string anna in to  two parts,

an & na

so you need to expand both parts until the part length is less than or equal to one. so your required function is the below one.

```
function expand(word) {
    if (word.length<=1) {
        return word;
    } else {
        mid = word.length/2;
        return expand(word.substr(0,mid)) + " --- " + expand(word.substr(mid,word.length));
    }
}

document.write(expand("anna"));
```

Comment: this reproduce a --- n --- n --- n --- a

Comment: I think OP wants to also visualize the process steps. PS: You need to put `var` in front of `mid`.